# NoMethodError in Admin::Programs#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I recently installed ActiveAdmin.

I have added one `Model` successfully as an Active Admin Resource, and subsequently went to localhost:3000/admin and created a couple test objects.

When I add a second `Model` which `belongs_to` the first I get the following error, when I navigate through the dashboard and I try to create a new object of this latter model:

```
NoMethodError in Admin::Programs#new  
Showing /Users/df/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-  7a2a31067e99/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `sss_center_id' for #<Program id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
Extracted source (around line #1):
1      
insert_tag renderer_for(:new)
```

N.B. SssCenter is the model name of the parent Model which `has_many` Programs (the second model that throws the error)

When I run `rake routes` I see that I have the following path:

```
     new_admin_program GET        /admin/programs/new(.:format)             admin/programs#new
```

which is the path that is being called with the action `admin/programs#new`. My question is: where do you define controller methods that are namespaced with ActiveAdmin? I tried going to `app/admin/` but I don't think you do it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Program` belongs to `SSS Center` then what you are missing in your program model is a column for the foreign key to SSS Center

To create that column you can begin by creating a new migration

```
rails g migration AddSssCenterToProgram
```

and editing this code inside of your `db/migrate/<name_of_migration>.rb`

```
class AddSssCenterToProgram < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :programs, :sss_center_id, :integer
  end
end
```

run `rake db:migrate`

Now you should have an attribute for `program` called `sss_center_id` to which the primary key of a specific SSS Center will be stored.  You shouldn't have anymore problem associating it with your first model.

Comment: thank you. I was under the impression that happened by Rails magic when you create a `has_many` and `belongs_to` statements...